# Give permission to Managed Identity to write index policy of Cosmos DB container

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-rbac

Is there a role or an action that can be assigned to a Managed Identity to allow it to write the index policy of a Cosmos DB container?

Neither `DocumentDB Account Contributor` nor `Cosmos DB Operator` nor `Owner` seem to suffice.

The code for writing the index policy using the .NET `CosmosClient` looks like this:

```
ContainerResponse containerResponse = await this.container.ReadContainerAsync();

containerResponse.Resource.IndexingPolicy = ...; // set or manipulate the index policy

await this.container.ReplaceContainerAsync(containerResponse.Resource);
```

Comment: How are you attempting to update the Index Policy? Can you please share the code?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I've added a code fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Data Plane SDKs such as `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` to perform Management Plane operations when using MSI authentication.

The operation you are attempting is probably failing with an error, that error has an `aka.ms` link in its message that points to: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac#permission-model

To perform Management Plane operations with MSI auth you need to use the Management Plane SDKs, such as [Azure.ResourceManager.CosmosDB](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.CosmosDB/) for .NET.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of this other package. So `Azure.ResourceManager.CosmosDB` has methods for writing the index policy? And do you know which role or permission is required?

Comment: It has method to update a Container (any properties inside). [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftdocumentdb) is the list of all available permissions although there are already some [roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/role-based-access-control#built-in-roles) that might be able to perform it (Owner for sure)